# How to check a propery of an object inside another object exist?

Tags: javascript

Using the following array with two objects that include another object inside I would like to know if there is a way to find which is the applicationID has applicantID equal with "5bd3480af09ddf0258c3a31d"

```
Array [
  Object {
    "__typename": "JobApplication",
    "_id": "5be097753397465946e051fd",
    "applicant": Object {
      "__typename": "User",
      "_id": "5bd83b9a62a9f33cf0f1033b",
    },
  },
  Object {
    "__typename": "JobApplication",
    "_id": "5bdc7c8b3241cb5bc10ac694",
    "applicant": Object {
      "__typename": "User",
      "_id": "5bd3480af09ddf0258c3a31d",
    },
  },
]
```

So in this case it has to return "5bdc7c8b3241cb5bc10ac694".

This are my two constants first will return the user id and second will return only the applications id.

```
const { _id } = this.props.getMe.me._id;
const applicationID = getJobApplicationsForThisJob.map(application => application._id);
```

I could check if the user id is in any of the objects like this

```
const applicantId = getJobApplicationsForThisJob.map(user => user.applicant._id);
const hasApplied = applicantId.includes(_id);
```

Thanks

Comment: This isnt JSON.  JSON wouldnt have *Object* and *Array* in the snippet

Comment: @Fallenreaper graphQL

Comment: Ahh, good to know

Comment: @Fallenreaper its similar to JSON

Comment: Since you are using Javascript, I was under the assumption you were giving valid Json.  Anyways, It looks like what you want to do is something akin to:  `let isContained = list.where( (obj) = > obj.applicant._id == _id).length != 0;`

So it looks through the list where the applicant has an _id == id and then checks the resulting list for a size to see if anything returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

```
var item = arr.find(function(x) {
  return x.applicant._id == find;
});
```

The `find` method returns the first found item or undefined if a record was not found.

```js
var arr = [{
  "__typename": "JobApplication",
  "_id": "5be097753397465946e051fd",
  "applicant": {
    "__typename": "User",
    "_id": "5bd83b9a62a9f33cf0f1033b",
  }
}, {
  "__typename": "JobApplication",
  "_id": "5bdc7c8b3241cb5bc10ac694",
  "applicant": {
    "__typename": "User",
    "_id": "5bd3480af09ddf0258c3a31d",
  },
}];

var find = "5bd3480af09ddf0258c3a31d";

var item = arr.find(function(x) {
  return x.applicant._id == find;
});


console.log(item != undefined ? item._id : "Not Found");
```

Comment: This suggested callback is not re-usable since it relies on the scoped variable `find` being defined, though this can be amended by wrapping `arr.find(...)` in a reusable function like `const findByApplicantId = (array, id)  => array.find(({ applicant: { _id } }) => _id === id);` then use `var item = findByApplicantId(arr, find);`

Comment: Also in the future, try to avoid creating multiple answers. Just edit your deleted answer and undelete it. The only exception to that should be if you have a downvoted answer and you submit a new answer that's fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Javascript, you would want to do something like my comment,

```
let _id = "5bd3480af09ddf0258c3a31d";
let list = [];  //your list of objects.
let applicationResults = list.where( (app) => app.applicant._id = _id);
if (applicationResults.length == 0){
  console.log("no applicantion with this applicant found.");
}else {
  console.log("Found " + applicationResults.length + " Applications from this Applicant")
  return applicationResults;
}
```